# accessing url with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

On a route /catalog/genres I am rendering list of genres

[image: react-router-link]

{genre.url} generates url such as: /catalog/genre/5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266f3
Where or how can I get access to that url?

I tried something like this (stupid I know), returns nothing.

[image: with Route]

Comment: In order to help other people to help you: please do not post pictures. Instead copy the code and format it with the tools s provided by Stack Overflow

Comment: oh sorry! will consider next time.

Answer (score 1):

Route components automatically receive a prop called match. This prop contains the path and params, which should serve you well.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below route.

```
<Route path={"/catalog/genre/:id"} render={()=><h3>does not work</h3>} />
```

Or

```
<Route path={"/catalog/:genre/:id"} render={()=><h3>does not work</h3>} />
```

Hope it's resolved your issue.

Comment: @d_oram I'd like to help you and hope this answer will help you well. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Your route should looks like

```
<Route 
    exact
    path="/catalog/genre/:id"
>
```

which is same for all ids

```
<Link url="/catalog/genre/5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266f3">Link Name1</Link>
<Link url="/catalog/genre/5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266f4">Link Name2</Link>
<Link url="/catalog/genre/5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266f5">Link Name3</Link>
```

In your case, route component will come outside of loop and it will as it is mentioned above.